# Raspberry PI 4B + Ubuntu 22.04 - Fails connecting to WiFi 5G

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, wifi

5G access point Casa.Fred disappears a few moments after boot.

**AP list right after reboot - AP Casa.Fred is listed, as expected**

root@FRED-PI:~# **nmcli dev wifi list**

IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY

```
        68:02:B8:FA:3A:A2  Casa.Fred2G                       Infra  7     195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
*       68:02:B8:FA:3A:A3  Casa.Fred                         Infra  149   540 Mbit/s  94      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
        B0:5C:DA:98:C4:27  DIRECT-26-HP DeskJet 2600 series  Infra  7     65 Mbit/s   70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
        BC:2E:48:D5:34:56  2.4G Vaz                          Infra  10    405 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
        B4:2A:0E:19:E9:D7  Cesar                             Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
        BC:2E:48:D5:34:57  5G Vaz                            Infra  44    405 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA2
        00:25:F1:EB:F3:88  MOTOROLA-DF364                    Infra  11    54 Mbit/s   40      ▂▄__  WPA1
```

**Journal shows NetworkManager startup complete**

root@FRED-PI:~# **journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager**

```
Oct 21 13:05:12 FRED-PI systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Oct 21 13:05:13 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368313.7093] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Oct 21 13:05:13 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368313.7097] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, ZZraspi-wifi-powersave-off.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (e>
Oct 21 13:05:13 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368313.7390] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Oct 21 13:05:13 FRED-PI systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Oct 21 13:05:13 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368313.8151] manager[0xaaaae1a52030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Oct 21 13:05:13 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368313.8153] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.0955] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.0956] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "FRED-PI"
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.1340] dns-mgr[0xaaaae1a2f280]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.1556] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/platform/soc/fe300000.mmcnr/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:0001/mmc1:0001:1/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver brcmfmac)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.1573] manager[0xaaaae1a52030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.1575] manager[0xaaaae1a52030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.2616] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.3077] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.3564] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.4478] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.5088] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.5113] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.5116] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.5119] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.5678] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.5681] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.5682] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.5775] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.6619] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.6622] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.6634] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.6740] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.6753] device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.6873] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.6893] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.6904] device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 21 13:05:14 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368314.7461] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Oct 21 13:05:15 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368315.1847] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Oct 21 13:05:15 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368315.1852] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlan0 created
Oct 21 13:05:15 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368315.1861] manager: (p2p-dev-wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Oct 21 13:05:15 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368315.1870] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 21 13:05:15 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368315.1885] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:15 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368315.1913] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:15 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368315.2542] modem-manager: ModemManager not available
Oct 21 13:05:16 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368316.1649] modem-manager: ModemManager now available
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0272] policy: auto-activating connection 'netplan-wlan0-Casa.Fred' (7379dc56-f256-3838-ab08-eeb691cc128d)
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0289] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'netplan-wlan0-Casa.Fred' (7379dc56-f256-3838-ab08-eeb691cc128d)
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0293] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0299] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0309] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0346] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'netplan-wlan0-Casa.Fred' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0353] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0364] sup-iface[87d8ddb652ae569c,0,wlan0]: wps: type pbc start...
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0411] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0433] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0451] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'netplan-wlan0-Casa.Fred' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0469] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Casa.Fred'
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0470] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0472] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0473] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0473] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0892] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
Oct 21 13:05:18 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368318.0893] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> associating
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.7914] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.7922] device (eth0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.7945] policy: auto-activating connection 'netplan-eth0' (626dd384-8b3d-3690-9511-192b2c79b3fd)
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.7958] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'netplan-eth0' (626dd384-8b3d-3690-9511-192b2c79b3fd)
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.7961] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.7969] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.7991] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8001] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8498] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.85
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8550] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8699] device (eth0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8706] device (eth0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8721] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8723] policy: set 'netplan-eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8819] device (eth0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 21 13:05:19 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368319.8833] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.5832] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.5834] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Casa.Fred"
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.5835] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.5839] device (wlan0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.5846] dhcp4 (wlan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.6256] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.87
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.6386] device (wlan0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.6489] device (wlan0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.6495] device (wlan0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.6554] device (wlan0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 21 13:05:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368347.6590] manager: startup complete
```

**AP list a few moments after Wifi connected - AP Casa.Fred disappears**

root@FRED-PI:~# **nmcli dev wifi list**

IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY

```
    68:02:B8:FA:3A:A2  Casa.Fred2G                       Infra  7     195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
    B0:5C:DA:98:C4:27  DIRECT-26-HP DeskJet 2600 series  Infra  7     65 Mbit/s   69      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
    BC:2E:48:D5:34:56  2.4G Vaz                          Infra  10    405 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
    B4:2A:0E:19:E9:D7  Cesar                             Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
    BC:2E:48:D5:34:57  5G Vaz                            Infra  44    405 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA2
    90:55:DE:4A:37:A8  45B 2G                            Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
    5C:76:95:95:2E:74  2.4G_ROSE VIEIRA                  Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
    00:25:F1:EB:F3:88  MOTOROLA-DF364                    Infra  11    0 Mbit/s    39      ▂▄__  WPA1
    84:0B:BB:24:97:40  Lousada                           Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2
    F4:6F:ED:53:4C:08  Adriana 2G                        Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
    48:83:C7:9E:3A:2A  Camargo                           Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
    5C:76:95:95:2E:75  5G_ROSE VIEIRA                    Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  24      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2
    86:7E:CA:8C:12:0E  Autiere                           Infra  36    540 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2
```

**And the following lines are added to journal:**

```
Oct 21 13:06:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368407.9605] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 21 13:06:47 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368407.9608] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 21 13:06:48 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368408.0585] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 21 13:06:48 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368408.0587] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 21 13:07:02 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <warn>  [1666368422.9395] device (wlan0): link timed out.
Oct 21 13:07:02 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368422.9398] device (wlan0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:07:02 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <warn>  [1666368422.9432] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'netplan-wlan0-Casa.Fred'
Oct 21 13:07:02 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368422.9474] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 21 13:07:02 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368422.9729] dhcp4 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 21 13:07:02 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368422.9731] dhcp4 (wlan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 21 13:07:02 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368422.9733] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed no lease
Oct 21 13:07:06 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368426.2130] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Oct 21 13:07:06 FRED-PI NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1666368426.2133] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
```

**Netplan configuration:**

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        eth0:
          dhcp4: true
          optional: true
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                "Casa.Fred":
                    password: "***********"  - Actual password ommited here
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
```

**Network Interface Data**

root@FRED-PI:~# **lshw -C network**

```
  *-interface:0
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 43430
       vendor: Broadcom
       physical id: 1
       bus info: mmc@1:0001:1
       logical name: mmc1:0001:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: e4:5f:01:cb:1f:4a
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.241 firmware=01-703fd60 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE
802.11

  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: eth0
       serial: e4:5f:01:cb:1f:48
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=5.15.0-1017-raspi duplex=full ip=192.168.0.85 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
```

**Remarks:**

1. AP Casa.Fred works fine with all my devices (laptops, smartphones, tablet, STBs, TVs etc)
2. All software on RPi are up to date
3. Connecting to 2G on same router works fine (Access Point Casa.Fred2G)

Comment: Have you set your country? So wifi knows legal bands.

Comment: It's in `/etc/wpa_supplicant` or thereabouts.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. Yes, the country is correctly set to Brazil (BR).

Comment: Supplicant journal lines (prefix removed to fit here):

wpa_supplicant[748]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant

wlan0: WPS-CANCEL

wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'Casa.Fred'

wlan0: Associated with 68:02:b8:fa:3a:a3

wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 68:02:b8:fa:3a:a3 completed [id=0 id_str=]

wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0

wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=BR

wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=68:02:b8:fa:3a:a3 reason=3 locally_generated=1